# PayPal Webhook request format

Tags: python, post, paypal, request, webhooks

Any chance someone could help me understand how I could handle paypal webhooks better? I believe the webhook sends a POST request to the chosen URL, but how is the information encoded? Is it a raw JSON? form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webhook sent to the chosen URL from PayPal is in JSON form.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#simulate-event

```
{
  "id": "8PT597110X687430LKGECATA",
  "create_time": "2013-06-25T21:41:28Z",
  "resource_type": "authorization",
  "event_version": "1.0",
  "event_type": "PAYMENT.AUTHORIZATION.CREATED",
  "summary": "A payment authorization was created",
  "resource_version": "1.0",
  "resource": {
    "id": "2DC87612EK520411B",
    "create_time": "2013-06-25T21:39:15Z",
    "update_time": "2013-06-25T21:39:17Z",
    "state": "authorized",
    "amount": {
      "total": "7.47",
      "currency": "USD",
      "details": {
        "subtotal": "7.47"
      }
    },
    "parent_payment": "PAY-36246664YD343335CKHFA4AY",
    "valid_until": "2013-07-24T21:39:15Z",
    "links": [
      {
        "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/2DC87612EK520411B",
        "rel": "self",
        "method": "GET"
      },
      {
        "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/2DC87612EK520411B/capture",
        "rel": "capture",
        "method": "POST"
      },
      {
        "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/2DC87612EK520411B/void",
        "rel": "void",
        "method": "POST"
      },
      {
        "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-36246664YD343335CKHFA4AY",
        "rel": "parent_payment",
        "method": "GET"
      }
    ]
  },
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/notfications/webhooks-events/8PT597110X687430LKGECATA",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/notfications/webhooks-events/8PT597110X687430LKGECATA/resend",
      "rel": "resend",
      "method": "POST"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When PayPal sends events to my webhook, every array including POST, GET, and REQUEST are empty except SERVER of course.  !!! help!

Comment: @zdanman Try

    file_get_contents('php://input')

instead of reading the $_POST variable. I do not know why Paypal sends the $_POST request in a way where reading it through $_POST would be possible, but the above way works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

instead of reading the $_POST variable. I do not know why Paypal sends the $_POST request in a way where reading it through $_POST would be possible, but the above way works for me.